# Dimensions of a cylinder when looking from angle

Tags: geometry

[image]

I'm looking at a picture of cylinder taken from an unknown angle, the picture looks similar to the diagram above. When measuring the image on the picture, line A is 4.24" long, line B is 2.25" long, and line C is 1.88" long. In the actual object, I know lines A and B are both 15" in length. How long is line C in the actual object?

I'm trying to find the width of a tire rim from a picture. I know it is a 15" rim, but I don't know the width (which would be C).

Comment: To find magnification for same relative lengths proportion  of  given projection lengths $(A,B,C)$ ?

Comment: Does the 15" rim mean the circumference of the circle is 15"?

Comment: @peterwhy 15" is the diameter.